# How do I get positive results only from my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want `` (`Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent`) `` to be positive only. I do not want it if the result is negative. I have tried `` (`Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent`)>0 `` in the SELECT clause but it did not work.

```
 SELECT 

        `Account Executive`,
        `DC Clerk`,
        `Project Number`,
        Manufacturer,
        `Open Project Date`,
        `DUE DATE`,
        `Project Status`,

       ( `Pre-Scan Hours Planned`+
        `Radiated Emissions Hours Planned`+
        `Conducted Emissions Hours Planned`+
        `Harmonic and Flicker Hours Planned`+
        `ESD Hours Planned`+
        `RF Immunity Hours Planned`+
        `EFT Hours Planned`+
        `Surge Hours Planned`+
        `Conducted RF Hours Planned`+
        `Magnetic Field Hours Planned`+
        `Voltage Dips Hours Planned`+
        `EUT Photos and Data Sheet Hours Planned`+
        `Data Sheet Hours Planned` ) AS 'Total Planned Hours',

       ( `Pre-Scan Time Spent`+
        `Radiated Emissions Time Spent`+
        `Conducted Emissions Time Spent`+
        `Harmonic and Flicker Time Spent`+
        `ESD Time Spent`+
        `RF Immunity Time Spent`+
        `EFT Time Spent`+
        `Surge Time Spent`+
        `Conducted RF Time Spent`+
        `Magnetic Field Time Spent`+
        `Voltage Dips Time Spent`+
        `EUT Photos and Data Sheet Time Spent`+
        `Data Sheet Time Spent` ) AS 'Total Spent Hours',

        ( (`Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent`)+
        (`Radiated Emissions Hours Planned`-`Radiated Emissions Time Spent`) +
        (`Conducted Emissions Hours Planned`-`Conducted Emissions Time Spent`) +
        (`Harmonic and Flicker Hours Planned`-`Harmonic and Flicker Time Spent`) +
        (`ESD Hours Planned`-  `ESD Time Spent`) +
        (`RF Immunity Hours Planned`-`RF Immunity Time Spent`) +
        (`EFT Hours Planned`-  `EFT Time Spent`) +
        (`Surge Hours Planned`-`Surge Time Spent`) +
        (`Conducted RF Hours Planned`-`Conducted RF Time Spent`) +
        (`Magnetic Field Hours Planned`-`Magnetic Field Time Spent`)+
        (`Voltage Dips Hours Planned`-`Voltage Dips Time Spent`) +
        (`EUT Photos and Data Sheet Hours Planned`-`EUT Photos and Data Sheet Time 
        Spent`) +
        (`Data Sheet Hours Planned` -`Data Sheet Time Spent`)) AS 'Remaining Hours',

        (`Pre-Scan Status`+
        `Radiated Emissions Status`+
        `Conducted Emissions Status`+
        `Harmonic and Flicker Status`+
        `ESD Status`+
        `RF Immunity Status`+
        `EFT Status`+
        `Surge Status`+
        `Conducted RF Status`+
        `Magnetic Field Status`+
        `Voltage Dips Status`+
        `EUT Photos Status`+
        `Data Sheet Status`) AS 'Items Remaining'

    FROM 
        EMCtestplan
```

---

Let me explain better, For example we have below query:

I need this:

```
select
a,
b,
c,
(f1-f2)+(f3-f4)+(f5-f6) as Sum
from table
```

I want `(f1-f2)+(f3-f4)+(f5-f6) as Sum` this code just calculate the positive formula. For example do not calculate the sum if `(f3-f4)` is negetive and just calculte `(f1-f2)+(f5-f6)`

PLEASE Some body Help me!

Comment: Put that statement in a `Where` clause.

Comment: I suggest that you update your question and remove extraneous "answers"

Comment: Please do not post answers to add information that clarifies your question. Instead, use the [edit] link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to use when it is negative? I will assume that you want to use zero. Change:

```
(`Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent`)
```

to:

```
(CASE WHEN `Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent` > 0
      THEN (`Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent`)
      ELSE 0 END)
```

You can use something other than zero if you like.

Comment: OH my God. I think This will work....I forgot this syntax.... let me try it, Thanks a lot

Comment: Where can I use this in select?

Comment: You can use it anywhere you want. In your case, you probably want to use it instead of the `(Pre-Scan Hours Planned-Pre-Scan Time Spent)` like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot...It work...I have another question... is that possible to add another condition after first WHEN...THEN? for example when...then and when...then...else 0 end

Comment: It means like if cluase   -> if(...) "do something" else if(...) "do somthing" else ...

Comment: Yes, you can. If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I mean can i write this?

Comment: CASE WHEN `Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent` > 0
      THEN (`Pre-Scan Hours Planned`-`Pre-Scan Time Spent`)
      ELSE WHEN ...<0 THEN ... ELSE 0 END)

Comment: I want to use 2 when in one case

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: You can have several `WHEN` for the same `CASE`. [Look at this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

Comment: Thanks you are very very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing to an answer to the new question the OP has posed as an answer

OP has:

```
select
a,
b,
c,
(f1-f2)+(f3-f4)+(f5-f6) as Sum
from table
```

> I want (f1-f2)+(f3-f4)+(f5-f6) as Sum this code just calculate the
>   positive formula. For example do not calculate the sum if (f3-f4) is
>   negetive and just calculte (f1-f2)+(f5-f6)

If you are only concerned about (f3-f4) being negative:

```
select
a,
b,
c,
CASE 
    When (f3-f4) < 0 then (f1-f2)+(f5-f6)
    Else (f1-f2)+(f3-f4)+(f5-f6)
END as Sum
from table
```

If the concern that any of (f1-f2), (f3-f4), (f5-f6) is negative, then I would handle differently

```
select
a,
b,
c,
(MAX(f1-f2,0) + MAX(f3-f4,0) + MAX(f5-f6,0) as Sum
from table
```

Comment: You need backticks around the name since it contains space and hyphen.

Comment: Thanks for answer...But It cannot help becuase if you add something in where cluase it will effect to all collumn...and I want to have this positive in just 4th collumn for each of them... I do not want to effect in my all column for retreive data